# this context changes while assigning

Tags: javascript

This question is from [ECMA-262](http://dmitrysoshnikov.com/ecmascript/the-quiz/) quiz

```
var x = 100;
var foo = {
  x: 50,
  bar: function(){
    return this.x;
  }
}
console.log(foo.bar()); //returns 50
console.log((foo.bar = foo.bar)()); //returns 100
```

How does the `this` context changes in the second `console` statement ? or in general what object does equals to(assigning) operation returns the global object ?

Comment: (foo.bar)() is same as foo.bar() but different from (foo.bar = foo.bar)() , Try it in your browser console and see the difference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`foo.bar` (a [member operator](http://es5.github.com/#x11.2.1)) evaluates to a [Reference](http://es5.github.com/#x8.7) "*the property "bar" on an object*", and this will be treated special when [calling it](http://es5.github.com/#x11.2.3).

`(foo.bar = foo.bar)` (an [assignment](http://es5.github.com/#x11.13.1)) just yields the assigned value, and calling it will result in the global object being used as [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).

Answer (score 2):

`foo.bar = foo.bar` returns the function `foo.bar` which is then invoked via `(...)()`. Since the function was not invoked as a property of the object foo, its `this` will not be the foo object but rather in this case the global object.

Comment: Then (foo.bar)() also should return 100, but it returns 50, I tried also using ((foo.bar))() still getting 50, as foo.bar returns the function and invoked via (...)()

Comment: @Unspecified (foo.bar)() is equivalent to foo.bar(), you see you are using the return of the expression `foo.bar = foo.bar` as the function and not `foo.bar`. It is equivalent to some `(x = foo.bar)()`.